# f does not seem to respect :lmap

Tags: key-bindings

When trying to swap characters in certain modes, it struck me that I could not swap the character used after pressing `f`, such that `fa` actually jumps to the next `b` on the line. According to the vim documentation at `:h f`:

```
f{char}         To [count]'th occurrence of {char} to the right.  The
    cursor is placed on {char} |inclusive|.
    {char} can be entered as a digraph |digraph-arg|.
    When 'encoding' is set to Unicode, composing
    characters may be used, see |utf-8-char-arg|.
    |:lmap| mappings apply to {char}.  The CTRL-^ command
    in Insert mode can be used to switch this on/off
    |i_CTRL-^|.
```

This made me think that `:lmap a b` should solve my problem. `fa` still jumps to the next `a` however, even after starting vim with `vim -u NONE`. Am I missing something here?

Comment: Did you enable it with <c-^> in Insert mode, or by setting 'iminsert'? Works for me, btw.

Comment: That's indeed the setting I missed. Thanks! If you make it an answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to enable the language mapping with either `<C-^>` in Insert mode or with `:set iminsert=1`.

*References*
`:h f`
`:h i_CTRL-^`
`:h 'iminsert'`